# AJAX Response Issue in loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want ajax to update two different things. one is the clicked button class, and second is database record in while loop

Home

```
<?php
    $q = mysqli_query($cn, "select * from `com`");
    while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
    ?>
    com: <?php echo $f['com']; ?><br>
    <?php
        $q1 = mysqli_query($cn, "select * from `fvc` where m_id='" . $f['id'] . "' and log='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
        $q2 = mysqli_query($cn, "select * from `fvc` where log='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
    ?>
         <span class="result<?php echo $f['id']; ?>">
         <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($q1) > 0) { ?>
               <button value="<?php echo $f['id']; ?>" class="unfc"><i title="<?php echo mysqli_num_rows($q2); ?>" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
         <?php } else { ?>
               <button value="<?php echo $f['id']; ?>" class="fc"><i title="<?php echo mysqli_num_rows($q2); ?>" class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
         <?php } ?>
         </span>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('click', '.fc', function(){
                var id=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "vote.php",
                        data: {
                            id: id,
                            vote: 1,
                        },
                        success: function(){
                            showresult(id);
                        }
                    });
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.unfc', function(){
                var id=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "vote.php",
                        data: {
                            id: id,
                            vote: 1,
                        },
                        success: function(){
                            showresult(id);
                        }
                    });
            });

        });

    function showresult(id){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'result.php',
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                data:{
                    id: id,
                    showresult: 1
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $('.result'+id).html(response);

                }
            });
        }
```

result.php

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include('cn.php');

        if (isset($_POST['showresult'])){
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $q3=mysqli_query($cn, "select * from `fvc` where m_id='".$id."' and log='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
            $q4=mysqli_query($cn,"select * from `fvc` where log='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
            $numFavs = mysqli_num_rows($q4);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($q3)>0){
            echo '<button class="unfc" value="'.$id.'"><i title="'.$numFavs.'" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' ;
            } else {
            echo '<button class="fc" value="'.$id.'"><i title="'.$numFavs.'" class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' ;
                }   
            }   
    ?>
```

total number of row response is not updating for all comments in while loop.
I want loop ids to be updated as well in Ajax response for each comment So guide me whats wrong in my code

Comment: where in your code you are updating the favorite number of comments ? you're just selecting it. Not updating

Comment: @UsmanRana that is in the like.php, as i told its updating perfectly fine, even on click event, its updating in ajax response but update response is being shown only on the clicked comment until or unless i refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it will update only one element, your show_like function updates only one element, the one with id = #show_like'+id

if you want to update all span elements, create a function `update_likes()` and call it in the success instead of `show_like()`,

```
$(document).on('click', '.favcom', function(){
            var id=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "like.php",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        like: 1,
                    },
                    success: function(){
                        update_likes('.favcom');
                    }
                });
        });
```

then loop through the span elements and update each one of them, you can add a class `.show_like` if you have other spans and instead of `$("span")` put your class,

```
function update_likes(class){
    $(class).each(function() {
        show_like( $(this).val() );
    });
}
```

i hope this works, however, this is based on your code and it will make a lot of http requests ( in `show_like()` ) and i would recommend you improve it by trying to return all the data you need and loop through an array instead of making Ajax calls every time.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work :( i added a class to `<span class="showupdates">` and `$(".showupdates").each(function()`

Comment: Yes i have checked console, its showing nothing on click event. it updates the database, but not showing any response result on the current page

Comment: I forgot to montion that you have to do put update_likes in both of your clicks, on .favcom and .unfavcom, try adding a console.log i side update_likes and in the .each loop to see if it's actually getting called

Comment: Sir, i already did it. i updated both click events with their class. but it did not work that time so i informed you

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your comment :) , i reviewed my answer and your question and i actually made a mistake , you need `$(".favcom").each(function() {` and `$(".unfavcom").each(function() {` instead of `$(".showupdates").each(function() {` , i'm updating my answer,

Comment: Not updating anything now :(

Answer (score 0):

Your success function is targetting an element by ID, so a single specific element on the page. If you want to update multiple values you need to target a class or an element type which is common to the elements you want to target.

You have two classes for the buttons, so you could use those. You would have to change your PHP output so it just returns the new total number of likes, no HTML output needed.

Your success function in showLike would look something like this:

```
$(':button[value="'+id+'"]').toggleClass('favcom unfavcom');
$('.unfavcom').html('<i title="Remove from Favorite? - ('+response+'/20)" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
$('.favcom').html('<i title="Favorite Comment - ('+response+'/20)" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work, is there anything i am still missing?

Comment: Did you change your output in show_like.php? You need to look in the console window to see what is happening. If you post the url Ill take a look

Comment: Sir, i am just trying it in localhost, i hav'nt got any url yet :( and yes i updated php.. console is here `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.` *and Error* in next comment

Comment: console `Uncaught ReferenceError: button is not defined
    at Object.success (home.php:104)
    at fire (jquery-3.1.1.js:3305)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.js:3435)
    at done (jquery-3.1.1.js:9242)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.js:9484)
    at Object.send (jquery-3.1.1.js:9536)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.1.1.js:9143)
    at showLike (home.php:94)
    at Object.success (home.php:86)
    at fire (jquery-3.1.1.js:3305)`

Comment: Ah, my bad, the syntax of the first line was wrong. I've edited my answer with new code

Comment: its showing the response result fine, but on each click, its toggling every button as Liked comment. in whole loop until i refresh the page

Comment: Is the button value unique for each button? It would make it easier if you gave each button a unique id tag because then you could that element specifically without relying on the value selector

Comment: Yes, each button has a unique value as the value is comment's unique id.

Comment: Sir, I is there any solution?